# Catch an specific cookie in browser made by my script

Tags: javascript, php, perl, cookies

I made a web site using Perl code (CGI) which uses cookies to manage our users. Now I need to make a new script but using PHP, so I'd like to use the cookie what was created by my browser. I have the cookie name but I can't catch it (document. cookie, $_cookie).

The Perl site and the new script are in the same domain but in different directory.

- Perl (/cgi-bin/myperlfile.cgi)
- PHP (/myphpfile.php)

What can I do to use that already created cookie?

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistakes.
Thanks @Borodin.

Comment: Did you specify a path when you created the cookie? If you specified `/cgi-bin`, then your PHP script won't see it. If you specified `/` or if you didn't specify any, then your PHP script should see the cookie.

Comment: Show the code you used to create the cookie

Comment: Of course, my perl code is ...
&SetCookies("USRINFO",$usuario."|".$passwd."|".$clave_usr);

and then when i tried to catch using php ...
$myCookie = $_COOKIE['USRINFO'];

Comment: That doesn't show how you built the cookie at all. What's `SetCookies`? And you have yet to answer my first question.

Comment: You should be using https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI instead of http://www.scriptarchive.com/readme/cookielib.html ; also if you're using cookielib you're probably interested in http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are available from the browser at the time of page load.  If your CGI script set the cookie, and then the browser loads myphpfile.php, you would do something like this in myphpfile.php to get the cookie value into the PHP variable $myCookie:

```
<?php
$myCookie = $_COOKIE['name_of_cookie'];
```

Of course, this is assuming you know the name of the cookie and the domain and paths are set compatibly.

You can read all about it at http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: i have already tried that and also with javascript (document.cookie) but I can not catch my cookie. Something else...